# Can you specify the parent div in the same way that you can specify 'this' 'index' 'element' in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, parent

To effect the respective parent `div` of the elements being used in a function? I hope that made sense. I have been trying to find the answer in DOC's but am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: Translate what's `"'this' 'index' 'element'"` in jQuery? You can explain it better with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the parent div in jQuery you do something like this:

```
$('#div1').parent().doSomethingHere
```

this will iterate through the parent elements of the div. to specify a parent by id:

```
$('#div1').parent('#parent1').doSomethingHere
```

You can also access the parent of the current element in a function using "this":

```
$(this).parent().doSomethingHere
```

Comment: can i specify just one parent 'up' without using ID's ? If i have fifty buttons that effect only their respective parents ? I dont want to make 50 IDs and write code fifty times :P thanks for you thorough answer though!

Comment: edit* i just reread your last line of code, that seems like it will do the trick :D

Comment: Yes, by default if you don't specify a parent by attribute/id it should just grab the immediate parent 1 level up.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the parent of the element by

```
$('#yourelement').parent();
```

As per you i am effecting the parent by changing its `background colour` as below .

```
$('#yourelement').parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
```

To get all the parents ;

```
var parents= $("#yourElement").parents("*");
```

Comment: have a look on closet also .You may need that also .http://api.jquery.com/closest/.And note the difference between parent and close also :)